# Unable to upload 3gp, flv or mkv video format using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I have created a function to upload video using codeigniter framework. The function is able to upload mp4 format but I am having trouble with 3gp, flv and mkv formats. I have also gone through some searches which suggest adding mime type, which I did but even this isn't seem to be resolving the problem. You can find the code below. Any suggestions or solution will be most helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
 if(($this->input->post())){


        if($_FILES['add_vid_file']['error'] == 0){ 

            $config['upload_path']      = $this->location;
            $config['allowed_types']    = 'mp4|3gp|flv|mkv';
            $config['max_size']         = '20480';
            $config['file_name']        = time() . rand(100, 999);
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $flag = ($this->upload->do_upload('add_vid_file')) ? TRUE : FALSE;


            $_file_path = ($flag) ? $this->upload->data('file_name') : '';

            return ($this->Common_model->Add('resources', $this->getFileData($_file_path)))? $this->Common_model->fetchID() : FALSE;
        }
        else{
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$config['allowed_types'] ='*';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$config['allowed_types']  = 'mp4|MP4|3gp|3GP|flv|FLV|mkv|MKV';
```

check extension of 3gp, flv, mkv formats.

Comment: ok , what kind of file is .fr3 files? pdf is application, html is text, fr3 is?